# Android Jetpack Composable Draw Large List of coordinates

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of 36000 coordinates i need to plot on a canvas as dots.  Coordinates keep changing so i keep them in a map as part of my viewmodel as

`mutableStateOf(HashMap<Int, AtomicInteger>())` and the AtomicIntegers are being constantly updated.

The map is of angles and distance which i convert to coords on the canvas.  This works but my question is if this is the most efficient way to draw this - iterating through the map continuously seems inefficient

```
@Composable
fun lidarComposable(vm: MainViewModel) {
    MaterialTheme {
        Column {
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp, 500.dp)) {
                drawRect(Color.LightGray, topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f), size = Size(this.size.width, this.size.height))
                drawCircle(Color.Blue, 20F, this.center)
                vm.lidardata.data.forEach { (a, d) ->
                        val angle: Double = a.toDouble() / Lidar.relevence
                        val distance: Double = (d.get() / Lidar.relevence).toDouble()
                        val fixed = angle - vm.compass
                        val rad = fixed * PI / 180
                        val xx = this.center.x + (distance * cos(rad))
                        val yy = this.center.y + (distance * sin(rad))
                        drawCircle(Color.Red, 5F, Offset(xx.toFloat(), yy.toFloat()))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result is a gray canvas with a blue circle at center and the dots where i want them, just seems like there must be a better way.

After a while of collecting data from a spinning LIDAR I end up with a pretty good picture of the room but i'm new to compose and wonder if there is a better way to push changes to the canvas.[image]

Comment: Are you only interested in updating those points that change on the map? How is the map being updated with new values?

Comment: Yes this is LIDAR data (a spinning IR beam taking continuous distance to object readings) - a background thread is updating my map with new distances and eventually a picture of what is around the LIDAR is drawn in dots like a radar display.   All I really want is the latest angle / distance dot to show when it's changed.  What i posted works but it's a little janky.

Comment: But how specifically are you putting data into the map? Are these values being retrieved from a single source and added to the map or being added from different sources? In other words, is your map being updated asynchronously from different sources or atomically being updated? It also isn't clear how you can update the map when an entry only has a direction and angle. There is no ID to uniquely identify a point. If you can uniquely identify each point, there are ways to get a better performance without iterating through the entire data.

Comment: It's asynchronous data coming into my android app from an MQTT broker, so hundreds of async threads a second set the value of the map in my VM that's Map<Angle, Distance> - i tried to just maintain a map preloaded with AtomicIntegers in my VM because I was dealing with a lot of concurrency issues - I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm also converting my angle like 90.52 to 9052 and using that as the key in the map so so 360.00 degrees gives me a map of 36000 entries of angles to objects - seems like a good approach - if you can point me to how to do this that's be super helpful: "If you can uniquely identify each point, there are ways to get a better performance without iterating through the entire data."

Comment: So once values get added to the map, they can never be removed?

Comment: nope - they will just get a new distance reading when the environment changes - there will always be 360.00 degrees of data and 0..36000 records - i actually init the map with 36000 records and AtomicInteger(0) to avoid concurrency issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by preloading a list of Points that filters out noise like out of date values, 0s and useless large numbers. This code does what i need, i can see physical objects appear and change as the lidar moves through space with a compass heading.  Even showing point in the way as red, a blue line showing magnetic north and in the screen shot i can even see my shoulder and curved monitor.

```
@Composable
fun lidarComposable(vm: MainViewModel) {

    val maxRelevantAge = 5000

    MaterialTheme {
        Column {
            Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), onDraw = {
                val padding = 50
                val canvasWidth = size.width - padding
                val canvasHeight = size.height - padding

                drawRect(Color.LightGray, topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f), size = Size(this.size.width, this.size.height))
                drawCircle(Color.Blue, 20F, this.center)

                val north = 360 - vm.compass
                rotate(north) {
                    drawLine(
                        Color.Blue,
                        this.center,
                        Offset(this.center.x, (canvasHeight / 2 - canvasWidth / 2) + padding / 2)
                    )
                    drawCircle(Color.Blue, canvasWidth / 2, this.center, style = Stroke(5f))
                }

                rotate(vm.compass) {
                    drawLine(
                        Color.Red,
                        this.center,
                        Offset(this.center.x, (canvasHeight / 2 - canvasWidth / 2) + padding / 2)
                    )
                }

                    val obstructions: MutableList<Offset> = ArrayList()
                    val surroundings: MutableList<Offset> = ArrayList()
                    vm.lidardata.data
                    vm.lidardata.data.forEach { (a, d) ->

                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - d.timestamp.get() < maxRelevantAge) {
                            val angle: Double = a.toDouble() / Lidar.relevance
                            val distance: Double = ((d.distance.get() / Lidar.relevance).toDouble() / 2)
                            val fixed = angle - vm.compass
                            val rad = fixed * PI / 180
                            val xx = this.center.x + (distance * cos(rad))
                            val yy = this.center.y + (distance * sin(rad))

                            if (distance > 0 && ((angle < 20) or (angle > 340))) {
                                obstructions.add(Offset(xx.toFloat(), yy.toFloat()))
                            } else if (distance < canvasWidth / 2) {
                                surroundings.add(Offset(xx.toFloat(), yy.toFloat()))
                            }

                        }
                    }


                    drawPoints(obstructions, PointMode.Points, Color.Red, strokeWidth = 5f)
                    drawPoints(surroundings, PointMode.Points, Color.Black, strokeWidth = 5f)



            })

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the current state of the Compose Canvas class is designed to handle this situation. You have to draw everything prior to the canvas being composed and if anything changes, you need to redraw everything again. This is okay for lightweight drawings but not for something like displaying 36,000 points.

One solution is to use the older view-based canvas and cache the image that is drawn and reuse this cached image when updating it with new data. Instead of iterating through 36,000 items, you can use a Flow that sends the points to the drawing canvas in sequential order. As new points arrive, you feed them into the flow and when they are collected, they are drawn onto the canvas. But you need to also remove the last point on your canvas for the given angle before drawing the newer one. To remove the previous one, you need to read it's last value from the map. By using a flow, you only update the canvas whenever a new data point arrives.

Even if the composable (that is hosting your canvas) recomposes, you should be able to retrieve the cached canvas image and use that rather than having to rebuild the entire image by iterating over all the points in the map. You just need to make sure you place a reference to your canvas in a viewmodel so that it doesn't get destroyed when the composable is recomposed.